# How do i do math with object instance variables once i have created the object in java

Tags: java

I have constructed an object in java with integer instance variables, how do find the quotient of two of these variables after i have created the object.

The objects i have created are like this:

```
class Student(int score, int marks)
```

where score is the score he received in the test and marks is the max score in the test, how can i find the percentage he got, after i have created multiple students like:

```
Student student1 = new Student(60, 90);
```

where i want the program to print:

```
"student1 got "+((score/marks)*100)+"%"
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you have getter/setter methods in your `Student` class to access the fields `score` and `marks`?

Comment: Just like that, but `score / marks` returns 0 in your case, because of *integer division*. Change to `1.0 * score / marks` or `((double) score) / marks` or `score / (double) marks`.

Comment: Provide get functions to give access to the variables OR a private method that calculates the percentage without granting access to the private state.  I'd prefer the 2nd one.

Comment: How would a private method help here? Even if it calculates the percentage based on private fields, shouldn't it be public?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Public function, private variables.  See below.

Comment: Thanks guys, MC Emperor i used you method and works just right! cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend:

```
class Student {

    private int grade; 
    private int maxGrade;

    public Student(int grade, int maxGrade) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.maxGrade = maxGrade;
    }

    public double getPercentage() {
        return 100.0 * grade/maxGrade;
    }
}
```